# Overflow:Auto With Margins

Tags: css

I've got a simple `<ul>` which has a position of fixed, with the height set to 100% and overflow to auto.  This allows me to scroll when the height of window becomes less than the height of the unordered list.

The only problem with this is that I want the unordered list to be 30px from the top of the page.  When the scrollbars appear the bottom part of the `<ul>` is actually missing, and furthermore the bottom part of the scrollbar is missing due to the top margin.

Here's some sample markup:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
div#sidebar {
    width:148px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Any ideas how to get around this quirk?

**EDIT:** Argh, forgot to add position:fixed

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have the 30px on an element other than the height 100% element since the margin and the 100% add together to create the final element height (and: 100% + 30px > 100%). By putting a padding on a containing div, you can get the same effect.

Try this.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>

div#container {
    padding-top:30px;
}
div#sidebar {
    width:148px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem lay elsewhere for me.  The same problem is occurring using your solution.  This is under IE7 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As Joel said, margin + height add together, so you should use a container.

Also, bear in mind any possible outer margins or paddings. This should work perfectly (tested on IE7 + Opera 10), provided you don't have any other markup bothering there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            html, body{
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .container {
                padding-top: 30px;
                width:148px;
            }
            #sidebar{
                margin: 0;
                width:148px;
                height:100%;
                overflow:auto;
                background: red;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <ul id="sidebar">
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```